# Unable to change SKView backgroundColor

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, sprite-kit

This is with iOS 9. I am unable to set the background color of an SKView, it always renders with the default grey. Is there a way around this?

```
let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100)
let spriteView = SKView(frame: frame)
spriteView.backgroundColor = .blueColor()
self.view.addSubview(spriteView)
```

When the above code is run the SKView is grey instead of blue. What I really want to be able to do is set `allowsTransparency = true` but I can't get that to work if I can't change the background color to `clearColor`.

Anyone else running into this? Any workarounds?

**Update**

Even with @Danilo's suggestion, this still displays as grey:

```
let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100)
let spriteView = SKView(frame: frame)
spriteView.backgroundColor = .clearColor()
spriteView.allowsTransparency = true
spriteView.opaque = false
```

**Update**

Apparently setting the `backgroundColor` of an SKView has not effect, but if you do set it to anything then `allowsTransparency = true` doesn't work.

Comment: try to set opaque = NO

Comment: @Danilo still grey :(

Answer (score 4):

In addition to adding a `SKView`, we need a `SKScene` that is to be presented by the `SKView`; we then adjust/change the `backgroundColor` of the `SKScene`. A node, in turn, will be added by the scene.

For example:

```
//create a SKView, which takes up the same frame as our view
let spriteView = SKView(frame: self.view.bounds)

//adding spriteView as a child view of our view
self.view.addSubview(spriteView)

//Here, we create a scene, which is the root object of
//the graph
let scene = SKScene(size: spriteView.frame.size)
scene.backgroundColor = .orangeColor()

//As said, we present the scene with our SKView
spriteView.presentScene(scene)

//Here, we create a node, which will be added by our scene
//This node takes up a size that you originally created and has the 
//background color set to blue
let nodeFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100)
let node = SKSpriteNode(color: .blueColor(), size: nodeFrame.size)

//The following just serves to show how we can adjust the node's   
//position; I will leave that to you
node.position = CGPointMake(scene.frame.size.width - 200, scene.frame.size.height - 100)

//Finally, we add the node to our scene
scene.addChild(node)
```

Comment: Thanks! This wasn't quite the answer but it helped me find it. Apparently setting the `backgroundColor` of an SKView has not effect, but if you do try to set it to anything then `allowsTransparency = true` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    let spriteView = SKView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    let spriteKitScene = SKScene(size: spriteView.frame.size)
    spriteKitScene.backgroundColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    spriteView.presentScene(spriteKitScene)
    self.view.addSubview(spriteView)
```